# CakePHP fetching data from form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to get the value of input data in a cakephp form so that I can use it in a sql query to auto fill other data. Currently i'm trying to use $this->request->data but it's not showing any results when I change my customer. I want it to display the customer that is selected but currently it's just blank. Not sure if i'm trying to get the data correctly or displaying it incorrectly.

[image]
My add.ctp

```
<div class="invoices form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($invoice) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Invoice') ?></legend>
        <?php

            echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', ['options' => $customers, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'customers']);        ?>

    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>


<script>
            document.getElementById('customers').addEventListener('change',function(){
                alert(<?php echo $this->request->data('customers');
                ?>)
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: Did you check that `$this->request->data('customers')` is really set in this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
document.getElementById('customers').addEventListener('change',function(){
       alert(this.value);
 });
```